Why "Get-Content Function:\mkdir" is valid, but not "Get-Content Function:\ipconfig"?
I just ran into something useful but apparently esoteric as it's non-standard use of Get-Content; specifically: Get-Content Function:\mkdir. When I use this command in Powershell, it returns the entire function definition, and even the function body. Oddly enough, Get-Content Function:\ipconfig does not, even though it's listed literally alongside mkdir on the official documentation.
I've been studying ways of easily finding more info on cmdlets, object definitions, etc. in Powershell. This particular seems rather useful, however, it's hard to find more use of Get-Content in this context, as it's usually used somewhat differently.

what is mklink ? again, even after your update, my answer is explaining the issue. move is also an alias not a function. instead of updating the question changing the premise of the initial question, ask a new one...

are you going to keep editing your question until you get all the answers for all the different commands powershell can handle?

I'm editing to get the alias commands out, as that's not the answer I was looking for. I was trying to find out why Get-Content Function:\mkdir works, but so many other non-alias functions do not work with the same command. Including an alias was a simple mistake, as I've tried with dozens of others as well.

It makes sense because md is an alias of mkdir and mkdir is a function. If you target the alias: provider then it will resolve into the command it's pointing to:
Get-Content alias:\md

In this case, I'd recommend to use Get-Command instead if you're looking for the source code of a function.
$command = Get-Command md
$command -is [System.Management.Automation.AliasInfo] # True
$command.ResolvedCommand                              # mkdir
$command.ResolvedCommand.ScriptBlock                  # source code for mkdir


After updates to the original question the above answer doesn't make any sense. The original question was asking about an alias, and now the update is asking about an actual application (ipconfig) which of course there is no content to get because 1. Applications don't belong to the function: provider and 2. The source code is compiled.

My bad for placing the "md" command. Good catch. Still, I tried it with a whole lot of other functions and could not get it to work like it does in the particular instance of mkdir. What makes "mkdir" so special? Get-Command mkdir does not return even the params, let alone body. Still +1, thanks for pointing out my mistake pointing out md and not something else.

@The-Stanislav makes special compared to what? If you're asking about actual binary cmdlets then of course you won't be able to see their source code, it's already compiled. If you want to see the source code of those go to https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

A few of your comments may be answering my question, but I gotta do more research it looks. The documentation doesn't quickly identify the "class" of a command on the official website, seems like. They're all just grouped together.

I supposed the answer to this could help: where does Function:\ path point to? Is it just pulling from a file on my computer?
